# What is the easiest way to emulate a 'has focus' box around a wxButton?

Tags: c++11, button, focus, wxwidgets, default

I have a dialog and at the bottom a normal box sizer with 3 buttons in it.
When I do

```
m_buttonCancel->SetDefault();
```

the code works in the sense that pressing enter does cancel, but there is no  visual clue that this is the default button. I would like the button to have a rectangle around it, similar to when I say

```
m_buttonCancel->SetFocus();
```

Problem is: other widgets often have the focus, like wxTextCtrl widgets in the dialog. Then this focus border around the button disappears, but I would like it to stay.
Of course, I could put this button in a panel and set the border style, but then the size of this button would be different from the others or I must put these in separate panels also (but without border).

There must be an easier way to draw a border around a button, without changing the size of any button and without affecting the layout?

OS: CentOS, so wxWidgets uses Gtk.

Answer (score 1):

You have **also** to tell the dialog that button is a default item, depending on implementation\OS, it's handled differently

```
    SetDefaultItem(m_buttonCancel);
```

Though I may say that it's odd that you set Cancel as button which would react to Enter key, that's usually OKs role, the ESC key is handled separately.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will try it.
I want the user to explicitly click the OK button if he is satisfied with the changes. Some actions are rather 'dangerous' and could result in unwanted loss of data.

Comment: @user2943111 I actually figured that and i had had anecdote from real life about similar setup. doing this consistently may lead to opposite effects. This was done in complex accounting app, on every form. In confirmations they also applying cancel to Ok. Every user was found tapping wrong button, mostly tapping esc to cancel and ending approving and vice versa. It ended with refactoring after third employee had thrown their computer into the window and was diagnosed with severe stress disorder. It's better not to assign default button at all or set it to "Help" button

Comment: Cancel to Ok, I mean't key marked as Cancel. I.e. on modern pc would be Esc to OK.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just call both `SetDefault()` and `SetFocus()` on the button if this is what you want? Being "default" and being "focused" are different and neither one implies the other, so if you want both, just say so.

Comment: Because the focus goes to the first editable widget, which can be a wxTextCtrl or wxComboBox. if that widgets does not handle Enter, the action of the default button should be executed. Perhaps I will make it so that no action at all is done and the dialog will simply stay open.

Comment: If you don't want the button to be focused, it's perfectly fine. But why are you surprised that it doesn't appear focused in this case? This is very confusing...